# retain count in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, count

I have used `[anArray retainCount]` to get the retain count of array..(i know this should not be used but i am using just for learning retain concept)

Following is my code.

---

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"a,b,c,d"];
NSArray  *anArray =[[NSArray alloc]init];
NSLog(@"Retain count: %i", [anArray retainCount]);
anArray=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"Retain count: %i", [anArray retainCount]);
```

---

output

```
Retain count: 2
Retain count: 1
```

i think it should be opposite but....

Comment: ["What increases an object's retain count?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181010/what-increases-an-objects-retain-count) might be worth a read.

Comment: Sorry, But when i use this code it both time show retain count 1.

And this is correct because only Array object need to release for the array

Comment: As to why the orig retain count was 2 is anyone's guess.  (but as several folks mention you're not supposed to depend on the value).  It could be NSArray added itself to the autorelease pool?

Comment: Look at the documentation for the [retainCount](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCDAAJI) method. TL;DR: don't use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please do yourself a favor and **don't** look at `retainCount` trying to learn how the memory management rules work. Instead refer to the friendly Apple [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

In your examples:

```
 NSArray  *anArray =[[NSArray alloc]init];
```

You have allocated "anArray" (by calling `alloc`), so you are responsible for calling `release`.

```
anArray=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Now, you have obtained a new object (leaking the original, as seand said). This time, you do not own the object (because `componentsSeparatedByString` does not have `alloc` or `copy` in its name), so you must not release it.

Don't worry about what the retainCount is; tend to your own knitting and release objects that you should and don't release objects you don't own.

Comment: +1 for talking about it in terms of object ownership rather than using the antiquated "retain count" terminology.

Comment: you mean following code is correct?    

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"a,b,c,d"];  
NSArray  *anArray =[[NSArray alloc]init];
[anArray release];
anArray=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
//not release the anArray now

Comment: +1 it would be +2 if you'd mentioned that `new` also gives you an object you own and I was allowed to up vote twice.

Comment: @Online yes, although you would also need to release `str`.

Answer (score 5):

This line...
anArray=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

You squished the original assignment of 'anArray' (thus creating a leak).
In real life, you'd want to [anArray release] first.
That's why the retain count went back to 1.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that the retain count is unlikely to provide any useful information. It is **NOT** a good way to learn about retain and release concepts.

Comment: Ask a question if you want an answer. 'I think it should be the opposite but...' is a vague implication...