# Question about NSMutableArray, pointers and release

Tags: objective-c

How exactly does the addObject method of NSMutableArray work? Does it create a new instance and add it into the array or does it simply add a reference to the SAME object into the array?

If the answer is it only insert a reference to the object, then it leads to my next question:

Let's say I have the following method in one of my class ('list' is a NSMutableArray), gladly, this code works the way I wanted, but i just don't seem to fully understand why:

```
-(void)buyItem:(Item *)anItem
{
    Item * newItem = [[Item alloc]init];
    newItem.name = anItem.name;
    newItem.details = anItem.details;
    [list addObject:newItem];
    [newItem release];
}
```

So basically after calling [list addObject:newItem], there would now be total of two reference pointing to the same object right(newItem, and another one in the 'list' array)?

But why does releasing the newItem object here, doesn't wipe out the one in the 'list' NSMutableArray? Aren't they pointing to the same Object?

Answer (score 2):

When you are adding object to `NSMutableArray` using method `addObject:` it `retain`s added `object`. This is why you can `release` it later and use afterwards by accessing using `objectAtIndex:` method.

Comment: Ah yes i kinda get it now! Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

It adds a reference and then increases the objects retain count by one.  What you are doing is correct and it will still exist in the array with a retain count of one.

For your reference.
[What increases an object's retain count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181010/what-increases-an-objects-retain-count)

Comment: I see! Thanks. Gonna look up on retain counts now

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand the distinction between `release` and `dealloc`.  `release` simply decrements the "retain count", except that when the count is decremented to zero, `release` goes on to `dealloc` the object.

In general (except where documented otherwise), when you pass an object reference (ie, pointer) to an Objective-C object, and it keeps a copy of that reference beyond the duration of your call to it, it `retain`s the object on its own behalf, and it takes the responsibility to `release` the object when it is itself deallocated, or when the copy of the reference is nullified or overwritten.